# How to output signed message as a string from Phantom wallet

Tags: phantom, signature

I'm following this code from Phantom [doc](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/signing-a-message).

```
const provider = getProvider(); 
const message = "To avoid digital dognappers, sign below to authenticate with CryptoCorgis";
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
console.log('Signature : ' + JSON.stringify( signedMessage ) );
```

And the console output for `signedMessage` is below.

```
Signature : {"signature":{"type":"Buffer","data":[124,66,191,12,89,236,90,243,235,24,181,69,221,212,190,153,225,201,69,131,231,221,125,229,101,202,245,39,75,81,243,119,109,131,223,7,174,98,249,148,18,227,51,54,3,218,200,74,118,189,57,96,187,145,0,146,137,192,147,113,107,19,94,1]},"publicKey":"zGmof8SeyvHZqsTBjsKXSV"}
```

If I do signedMessage.toString(), I get

`Signature : [object Object]`

So how do I get just the typical message hash signature in hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 1):

You want to base58 encode the Uint8Array you get back. Typically the [bs58](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58) library is used for this.

```
import { encode } from 'bs58';

const message = new TextEncoder().encode('Please sign me :)');
const { signature } = await getProvider().signMessage(message, "utf8");
const base58 = encode(signature);
```